# Logic behind greedy Spider game?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics

What will be the best algorithm or logic that can be used for game like greedy spiders. 
As far as I can think it is based on A* algorithm ? Where the shortest path has to be a search between the spider and the flies.

Is there any better logic to implement that game?

I would like to learn the concept behind it. How they will be managing nodes and edges concept?

Comment: You may want to explain the concept for those who don't know what "greedy spider" is. You can edit your question to do so. People like annotated screen shots too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the accuracy you want the pathfinding to have and the amount of nodes you have. I would recommend the [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode), and then you can experiment with the [heuristics](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html). By example the Manhattan heuristic is really fast but doesn't got the accuracy like the Euclidean heuristic.

For a game like Greedy Spiders I would go for an accurate heuristic since there aren't much nodes, the Euclidean heuristic will suffice here.

This is a really good tutorial I once used for a game which explains a lot about it: [A* Pathfinding for Beginners](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)